# Using lengthOf.at.least in Chaijs Assertions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tdd, bdd, chai

I'm using [Chai.js](http://chaijs.com/). I have the following assertion

```
it('Expects subjects in the response body', () => {
  expect(response.body).to.be.an('object').that.includes.key("subjects");
 expect(response.body.subjects).to.be.an('array').that.has.lengthOf.at.least(1);
});
```

This doesn't pass I get an error message saying `Cannot read property 'least' of undefined`

But the following works fine.

```
it('Expects subjects in the response body', () => {
    expect(response.body).to.be.an('object').that.includes.key("subjects");
    expect(response.body.subjects).to.be.an('array').that.has.lengthOf(10);
});
```

So how am I using `.at.least()` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using an old (3.x) version of Chai. Upgrade to the newest version (4.0.2) to solve this problem.

```
npm i -D chai@latest
```